# Django Rest Framework: Dynamically Change Nested Object

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm using a `GenericForeignKey` and `ContentTypes`, how can I dynamically change the embedded object in a DRF serializer?

So for example:

```
class FooObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    """
    Represents every foo object
    """

    # 'bar=BarSerializer' if content_type is for Bar model.
    # 'baz=BazSerializer' if content_type is for Baz model.

    class Meta:
        model = models.StoreObject
        fields = ['id', 'content_type', 'object_id', 'content_object']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
class FooObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # skipped

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FooObjectSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            if isinstance(self.instance.content_object, Bar):
                self.fields['content_object'] = BarSerializer()
            # adjust these checks as you may wish
```

Comment: DO fields injected through this method still require definition in the fields array?